# Are there folding bikes with safer - locked steering?

Tags: folding-bicycle, steering

I see folding bikes have several more quick releases and possibly fail points - to fold in half and fold the steering column down, and connect the handlebar to steering column.

The really awkward thing is you'd have to get it in exactly the right position relative the wheel, and press really hard to lock it in - since a bump or rock can make it offset slightly resulting in a crash, are there bikes that lock the handle bars to the steering column in a way it cannot slip?

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re asking. Can you post a photo or link to one of the unsafe bikes you mention?

Comment: Decades of use would suggest there is nothing wrong with QR releases if used properly.  You can tighten a QR tighter than spec for a stem bolt (5nm), so no reason why the handle bars would twist.  Only remaining issue is setting the bars straight, which is not actually that hard once you have done it a few times.  A slight offset in handle bar to wheel will not make you crash.

Comment: You can get a version of QR that screws up to tighten-  DT Swiss RWS. Not sure if it could be used on a folding bike skewers due length. Have them on my MTB and have more confidence they are tightened correctly and cannot come loose than QR (although I am 100% happy QR is 'good enuf'. Fitting out a folding bike with them would probably cost more than many folders costs.

Comment: Properly tightened and correctly used QR fasteners are secure. Most accidents with QRs happen because of the lack of technical knowledge about the correct use.

Answer (score 1):

While I believe that your concerns about quick release locking mechanisms on folding bikes are unfounded, there is still an option if you absolutely won't use them. Many models of Brompton folding bikes will have a folding point on the steering column which will fold down like any other. To secure this, they don't use a quick release, but rather a metal clamp to press the two sections together with a nut to secure it. This is a large wing nut and is simply tightened by hand and not with any great amount of force. This can be seen at 1:50 in this video on unfolding the bike: